# Wordpress 'Illegal string offset' after updates

Tags: php, html, wordpress, debugging, wordpress-theming

My new client has a website that hadn't been updated in a long time. Now the PHP version, wordpress version and plugins are all up to date, but the Portifolio items now return this error:

Screenshot:

[image]

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'alt' in
>   /home/elite856/public_html/wp-content/themes/eliteled/functions.php on
>   line 679
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in
>   /home/elite856/public_html/wp-content/themes/eliteled/functions.php on
>   line 679

**This is line 679:**

```
'<img src="'. $ob_img['url'] .'" class="capa" alt="'. $ob_img['alt'] .'" />'.
```

**This is the whole function:**

```
$portfolio = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $portfolio->have_posts() ){
    while ( $portfolio->have_posts() ) { $portfolio->the_post();

        $ob_img     = get_field( 'imagem_de_capa' );
        $allcats    = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
        $cat        = $allcats[0]->name;
        $arrayData  = array(
                        'id'        => get_the_ID(),
                        'Titulo'    => get_the_title(),
                        'cat'       => $cat
                    );

        //Criando arrayData com as informações do portfolio
        if( have_rows('conteudo_do_portfolio') ){
            while( have_rows('conteudo_do_portfolio') ){ the_row();

                $tipo = get_field( 'tipo' );

                if( $tipo == 'foto' ){

                    if( empty( $arrayData['imgs'] ) ){
                        $arrayData['imgs'][] = array(
                            'full' => $ob_img['original_image']['url'],
                            'thumb' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( $ob_img['id'], 'thumb_portfolio' )[0]
                        );
                    }

                    $idImg      = get_sub_field('foto');

                    $arrayData['imgs'][] = array(
                        'full' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( $idImg, 'full' )[0],
                        'thumb' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( $idImg, 'thumb_portfolio' )[0]
                    );

                }else{

                    $idVideo = youtube_video_id( get_sub_field('video') );

                    $arrayData['imgs'][] = array(
                        'full'  => $idVideo,
                        'thumb' => "http://img.youtube.com/vi/{$idVideo}/0.jpg"
                    );

                }

            }
        }

        //'<li class="'. ( is_home() || is_front_page() ? 'item-home' : '' ) .'">'
        $conteudo .=    '<li>'.
                        '<img src="'. $ob_img['url'] .'" class="capa" alt="'. $ob_img['alt'] .'" />'.
                        '<div class="camada text-center">'.
                            '<a href="#" class="openModalPortfolio" data-tipo="'. get_field( 'tipo' ) .'" data-json=\''. json_encode( $arrayData ) .' \'\ >'.
                                //'<div class="'. ( is_home() || is_front_page() ? 'center-home' : 'center' ) .'">'.
                                '<div class="center">'.
                                    //'<img src="/wp-content/themes/eliteled/images/expand'. ( is_home() || is_front_page() ? '' : '-red' ) .'.png" class="expand" />'.
                                    '<img src="/wp-content/themes/eliteled/images/expand-red.png" class="expand" />'.
                                    '<span class="titulo">'. ( strlen( get_the_title() ) > 60 ? substr( get_the_title(), 0, 60 ) . '...' : get_the_title() ) .'</span>'.
                                    '<span class="cat">'. $cat .'</span>'.
                                '</div>'.
                            '</a>'.
                        '</div>'.
                        '<div class="camada camada-branca"></div>'.
                    '</li>';

    }
}
```

I've read that this warning used to not be printed like that before PHP 5.4, and also that it happens because it was expecting and array. I got little PHP skills, can someone give me a clue about what to do?

Comment: try to `var_dump($ob_img)` and see what it is containing.

Comment: string(48) "{"original_image":"6585","cropped_image":"6585"}"

Comment: Then `$ob_img['url']` and `$ob_img['alt']` don't exist. That's why PHP is showing that message.

Comment: So what can I do? It was working just before I updated

Answer (score 0):

Based from the dumped data, I am guessing the content of `original_image` is an attachment ID, so try this:

```
$img_params = json_decode($ob_img, true); // convert string to associative array
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($img_params['original_image']);
if ($url) {
  // we have the image url now so display the image here tag here
}
```

if it doesn't work, check the original theme/plugin developer if there is new update to the plugin/theme where this portfolio came from

Comment: Sorry I may really lack knowledge on this subject...where in the code should I be using your suggestion? I can't seem to make it work.